# PHP server does not see the database

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, deployment, google-cloud-platform

I made a laravel rest-api server on gcp, created a cloud database. However, my laravel server does not see it. If you set the container ip sql, login and password for the connection, then everything works locally. It does not work after deployment. 
app.yaml configured.

```sql
 DB_CONNECTION: mysql
 DB_HOST: localhost
 DB_PORT: 3306
 DB_DATABASE: mydbname
 DB_USERNAME: root
 DB_PASSWORD: passwordhere
 DB_SOCKET: /cloudsql/my-laravel:europe-west1:mydbinstancename
```

Answer (score 0):

Laravel gets all variables from the .env file in the root of your project.

Try entering all the information into your .env file such as:

```
DB_HOST=localhost
DB_USER=root
DB_PASS=passwordhere
```